# sum up member variables from an array with reduce

Tags: rust, functional-programming

With struct `Var` defined like this:

```
pub struct Var {
    val: i32,
}
```

I hope to add up all `val` from an array of `Var`s:

```
pub struct Var {
    val: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let var0 = Var { val: 0 };
    let var1 = Var { val: 1 };

    let array = [var0, var1];

    let sum = array.into_iter().reduce(|x, y| Var { val: x.val + y.val });
}
```

The code looks redundant to me as for every addition in `reduce`, a new `Var` was created. I hope to avoid such waste by adding only `val` yet it is impossible:

```
let sum = array.into_iter().reduce(|x, y| x.val + y.val);
```

> expected struct `Var`, found `i32`

The other way to fix it would be to fetch `val` from all `var` and then sum them up, which doesn't look too smart either:

```
let vals: Vec<i32> = array.into_iter().map(|var| var.val).collect();
let sum = vals.into_iter().reduce(|x, y| x + y);
```

Is there an elegant and efficient way to sum up all member variables from an array of struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain iterators without needing to `collect` intermediate results:

```
let sum = array.into_iter().map (|var| var.val).reduce(|x, y| x + y);
```

Or better, you can use [`sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) instead of `reduce`, and use `iter` instead of `into_iter` so that you won't destroy the original array:

```
let sum = array.iter().map (|var| var.val).sum::<i32>();
```

Another notable option is to use [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) to combine the effects of `map` and `sum` in a single call:

```
let sum = array.fold (0, |v, s| s + v.val);
```

Note that `reduce` returns `None` for an empty array and `Some (sum)` for a non-empty array, the other solutions return `0` for an empty array and the bare sum otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can destructure your structures and then call sum.

```rust
let sum: i32 = vals.into_iter().map(|Var {val}| val).sum();
```

It’s possible to shorten this via `fold`:

```rust
let sum: i32 = vals.into_iter().fold(0, |acc, Var {val}| acc + val);
```